# Thread safe when using Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

```
public async Task<Informations> DoSthAsync
{
   var informations = new List<Informations>();
   await Task.WhenAll(FirstTask(informations), SecondTask(informations));

   return informations;
}

public async Task FirstTask(List<Informations> list)
{
   await Task.Run( () => //do sth with list);
}

public async Task SecondTask(List<Informations> list)
{ 
  await Task.Run( () => //do sth with list);
}
```

I would like to ask, if this code may cause problems, when two task would be using same list?

Thank you.

Comment: The list is safe if nothing changes the list once the tasks begin.  Though in the long-term you probably should use `ImmutableList<>`

Comment: it depends on *do sth with list*

Comment: How is the `List` used by the first and second task? Is it going to be modified, for example by adding, replacing or deleting elements?

Comment: also `List` is not the only problem .... Even if you would only iterating the list **but changing `Informations item`** the code will be "thread unsafe" and  `ConcurrentBag` will not help ... so for changing collection `ConcurrentBag` is the way, but for modyfing item you need to `lock` on item

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If "*do sth with list*" means writing to the list, then this is not thread-safe, as `List<T>` is not a thread-safe collection. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8#thread-safety):

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8), but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it's being read. To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write operation. To enable a collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization. For collections with built-in synchronization, see the classes in the [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8) namespace. For an inherently thread-safe alternative, see the [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=netframework-4.8) class.

If your tasks are just reading from the list, and nothing is adding to it, then you're fine.

If your tasks need to write to the list, then the best solution depends on what exactly you're doing. If you're doing lots of CPU-bound work and then adding the results to the list, consider instead returning the results from `FirstTask` and `SecondTask`, and adding them to the list from inside `DoSthAsync`:

```
public async Task<List<Informations>> DoSthAsync()
{
    // Kick off both tasks
    var firstTask = FirstTask();
    var secondTask = SecondTask();
    await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);
    var informations = firstTask.Result;
    informations.AddRange(secondTask.Result);
    return informations;
}

public Task<List<Informations>> FirstTask()
{
    return Task.Run(() => ...);
}

public Task<List<Informations>> SecondTask()
{
    return Task.Run(() => ...);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the [concurrent collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8) to collect your results. If the order of the results is not important, use a `ConcurrentBag<T>`:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<Informations>> DoSthAsync
{
    var informations = new ConcurrentBag<Informations>();
    await Task.WhenAll(FirstTask(informations), SecondTask(informations));

    return informations;
}

public async Task FirstTask(ConcurrentBag<Informations> list)
{
    await Task.Run( () => //do sth with list);
}

public async Task SecondTask(ConcurrentBag<Informations> list)
{ 
    await Task.Run( () => //do sth with list);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `List<T>` is not thread safe. It would be advisable to use a collection which is or by adding a [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) which will prevent more than one thread accessing the block at once. Allowing you to safely mutate the list object whilst avoiding [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

```
lock(obj)
{
// informations mutations
}
```

You could use the `ConcurrentBag<T>` in this case instead of `List<T>`. [This collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.8) does support safe concurrent access and modification